# Using frozen token

Tags: solana-program

Is it possible to sell/send a token when the creator has frozen the account?

Answer (score 2):

When a token account has been frozen, it by definition cannot be transferred. So if you have a frozen token account, you won't be able to move the tokens within the account, and therefore not be able to sell them.

Comment: The creator can not freeze your token accounts though right? You need to sign for that.

Comment: The freeze authority tied to the mint account can absolutely freeze your token accounts.